# Calculate sum of multiple values in array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I have an array of objects like below, where I want to calculate the sum of `job_security, skill_development` and `company_culture` these fields.

```
reviews = [
  {
      id: 1,
      job_security: '2.0',
      skill_development: '3.0',
      company_culture: '4.0',
      is_anonymous: false,
      pros: 'Test 1...',
      cons: "Test 1...",
      created_at: '2022-10-19T19:07:18.000Z',
  },
  {
      id: 2,
      job_security: '3.0',
      skill_development: '1.0',
      company_culture: '2.0',
      is_anonymous: false,
      pros: 'Test 2...',
      cons: "Test 2...",
      created_at: '2022-10-19T19:07:25.000Z',
  },
  {
      id: 3,
      job_security: '4.0',
      skill_development: '1.0',
      company_culture: '2.0',
      is_anonymous: false,
      pros: 'Test 3...',
      cons: "Test 3...",
      created_at: '2022-10-19T19:07:35.000Z',
  }
]
```

I am expecting an output like this, where total sums of all the fields will return as an object

```
{
   job_security: '4.0',
   skill_development: '6.0',
   company_culture: '7.0',
}
```

This is what I have done :

```
const filteredKeys = [
  'job_security'
  'company_culture',
  'skill_development',
];

reviews.forEach((review: any) => {
   Object.keys(review).reduce(
      (accu: any, key: string) => {
         if (filteredKeys.includes(key)) {
            const rating = Number(review[key]);
            accu[key] = accu[key] || rating;
            accu[key] += rating;
         }
         return accu;
      },
      Object.create(null)
   );
});
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what you want. The sum of the fields you named in each of the three example objects of the top array are: 9, 6, 7 for elements 0, 1, and 2 respectively of the array of objects. But you show an expected output consisting of an object containing the three named properties and their values (which seem unrelated to the example array), and no sum. Could you show the exact output you need from the example array given?

Comment: The arithmetic in your example result is inconsistent with the example inputs.  `2.0 + 3.0 + 4.0 ≠ 4.0`, `3.0 + 1.0 + 1.0 ≠ 6.0`, `4.0 + 2.0 + 2.0 ≠ 7.0`  I hope people will still get the idea that it's supposed to be the sum.  I'm just saying the question would be better if it used the _correct_ sums.  People who are into programming are often quite particular about numerical details and consistency.  Many of us have made a career of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

simply use Array.reduce()  method :

```js
const reviews = [{id: 1,job_security: '2.0',skill_development: '3.0',company_culture: '4.0',is_anonymous: false,pros: 'Test 1...',cons: "Test 1...",created_at: '2022-10-19T19:07:18.000Z',},{id: 2,job_security: '3.0',skill_development: '1.0',company_culture: '2.0',is_anonymous: false,pros: 'Test 2...',cons: "Test 2...",created_at: '2022-10-19T19:07:25.000Z',},{id: 3,job_security: '4.0',skill_development: '1.0',company_culture: '2.0',is_anonymous: false,pros: 'Test 3...',cons: "Test 3...",created_at: '2022-10-19T19:07:35.000Z',}];

const sums = reviews.reduce( (s,e,i,{[i+1]:eNext})=>
  {
  Object.keys(s).forEach( k => s[k] += +e[k] );
  if (!eNext) // for the last (no next element), change values to string
    Object.keys(s).forEach( k => s[k] = s[k].toFixed(1) );
  return s
  }
  ,{ job_security: 0, skill_development: 0, company_culture: 0 });
  
  
console.log( sums )
```

Comment: Is there any way to make keys (`s.job_security`) dynamic?

Comment: @RAHULKUNDU  I have changed my answer for more "dynamic"   ...

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this

```js
const reviews = [
  {
      id: 1,
      job_security: '2.0',
      skill_development: '3.0',
      company_culture: '4.0',
      is_anonymous: false,
      pros: 'Test 1...',
      cons: "Test 1...",
      created_at: '2022-10-19T19:07:18.000Z',
  },
  {
      id: 2,
      job_security: '3.0',
      skill_development: '1.0',
      company_culture: '2.0',
      is_anonymous: false,
      pros: 'Test 2...',
      cons: "Test 2...",
      created_at: '2022-10-19T19:07:25.000Z',
  },
  {
      id: 3,
      job_security: '4.0',
      skill_development: '1.0',
      company_culture: '2.0',
      is_anonymous: false,
      pros: 'Test 3...',
      cons: "Test 3...",
      created_at: '2022-10-19T19:07:35.000Z',
  }
]

const filters =  [
  'job_security',
  'company_culture',
  'skill_development',
];
const output = reviews.reduce((acc, next)=> {
  for (let filter of filters){
      if (!(filter in next)) throw new Error(`Cannot find ${filter} in object`)
      if (!(filter in acc)) acc[filter] = 0;
      acc[filter]+= +next[filter];
  }
  return acc;
}, {})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce()` to do it

```js
let reviews = [
  {
      id: 1,
      job_security: '2.0',
      skill_development: '3.0',
      company_culture: '4.0',
      is_anonymous: false,
      pros: 'Test 1...',
      cons: "Test 1...",
      created_at: '2022-10-19T19:07:18.000Z',
  },
  {
      id: 2,
      job_security: '3.0',
      skill_development: '1.0',
      company_culture: '2.0',
      is_anonymous: false,
      pros: 'Test 2...',
      cons: "Test 2...",
      created_at: '2022-10-19T19:07:25.000Z',
  },
  {
      id: 3,
      job_security: '4.0',
      skill_development: '1.0',
      company_culture: '2.0',
      is_anonymous: false,
      pros: 'Test 3...',
      cons: "Test 3...",
      created_at: '2022-10-19T19:07:35.000Z',
  }
]

let keys =  [
  'job_security',
  'company_culture',
  'skill_development',
];
let result = reviews.reduce((a,v) =>{
  keys.forEach(k =>{
    a[k] = (a[k]??0) + (+v[k]) 
   })
  return a
},{})
console.log(result)
```